# Error because of Theano and NumPy variable types

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, theano

I am writing this code using numpy 1.9 and the latest version of Theano but I get an error which I can't fix. I doubt it could be the way I declare variable types but I can't work it around. I appreciate your suggestions. I want to product a matrix with a vector and sum it with a bias.

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
import numpy as np
import pprint
def test_theano_matrix():
   pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=3)
   W= T.fmatrix()
   x=T.fvector()
   b= T.fvector()
   y = T.dot(W,x) + b
   lin_func = function([W,x,b],y)
   dt = np.dtype(np.float)
   w_inp = np.matrix('1 0;0 1',dtype=dt)
   x_inp = np.matrix('2;1',dtype=dt)
   b_inp = np.matrix('0;0',dtype=dt)
   lin_func(w_inp,x_inp,b_inp)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   test_theano_matrix()
```

I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError(err_msg, data)
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function at index 0(0-based)',
'TensorType(float32, matrix) cannot store a value of dtype float64 without risking loss of precision. If you do not mind this loss, you can: 1) explicitly cast your data to float32, or 2) set "allow_input_downcast=True" when calling "function".', matrix([[ 1.,  0.],[ 0.,  1.]]))
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why don't you change `dt = np.type(np.float)` to `np.float64`? Additionally, the traceback explicitly tells you two ways you can solve the problem yourself...

Comment: It changes the error to `TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function at index 1(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (2, 1).')`

Comment: Again, the traceback is telling you the problem... The first error (at index 0) was fixed by using the correct dtype. Now, it's complaining about the argument at index 1, `x_inp`, and it's telling you the shape is wrong.

Comment: W_inp is 2x2 matrix and x_inp is 2x1 so I don't see why it is complaining about the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer comes from [Theano-users google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/ofTRZJz7oZQ).

You define your `x` variable as:

```
x=T.vector(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
```

This is it is a vector(i.e. it only have 1 dimensions).

```
x_inp = np.matrix('2;1',dtype=dt)
```

create a matrix, not a vector.

Theano graph are strongly typed, you must defined the good number of
dimensions. Just use:

```
x_inp = np.asarray([2,1])
```

---

I actually ended up defining `x` and `b` as matrices.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error and was able to resolve it by adding a `.theanorc` file containing the following two lines:

```
[global]

floatX = float32
```

That seemed to fix everything. However, your problem shows a slightly different error. But I think it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Error looks quite self-explanatory; have you tried:

```
dt = np.dtype(np.float32)
```

??

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem. I even tried theano.config.floatX but still get the same error.

Comment: With your solution the error is changed to:
   TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function at index 1(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (2, 1).')

Comment: @EhsanK.Mohammadi I haven't used Theano but the error seems to suggest it wants 1D input not 2D. Matrices by definition are 2D. Therefore you should try using numpy arrays instead of matrices: ie. x_inp = np.array([2,1],np.float32).